# ahk - ocr failed with camerb's library

Tags: ocr, autohotkey

I think that the camerb's library doesn't work very well, you can see the result of ocr in the following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyhqk.jpg

the same result is obtained if I try to do the ocr of a number, especially a float, the comma is often not recognized and the "0" is exchanged with the "o" :(

someone knows a more efficient library? ...thanks for the answers

if you want try the camerb's library, you can download it here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69127-ocrahk-library-for-recognizing-text-in-images/

Answer (score 0):

i have just tried Capture2Text software, it's working pretty good (in a window 650x450) but if i try to do the OCR of a little window (400x320), the maching is not really exactly.

does anyone know if AbbyyFineReader works with command prompt? because the developers of this software tell that it has a precision of 99,8%.

Comment: It looks like it has a developer SDK, but it does not support command line.